# Please retag multiple SU tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are currently quite a lot of tags that have alternatives on SU. Would it be possible to trim them down a bit? I'd do it manually, but there's way too many of them:

- vista (37) -> windows-vista (604)
- xp (22) and winxp (5) -> windows-xp (685)
- windows7 (8) -> windows-7 (906)
- office (10), ms-office (4) and msoffice (2) -> microsoft-office (60)
- ie (6) -> internet-explorer (69)
- ie6 (5) -> internet-explorer-6 (2)
- ie7 (2) -> internet-explorer-7 (5)
- ie8 (18) -> internet-explorer-8 (25)

Comment: The Windows OS versions are always flaring up no matter how many merges.

Comment: One of the reason I suggested a tag blacklist. Specifically on SU. It is getting extremely out of hand.

Comment: I know, and this seems to have gotten out of hand. Counting the stuff that should be retagged, it should be 119 manual retags. That's a lot!

Comment: I must be crazy or one of the other mods beat me to it. I can't find half these tags

Comment: A tag blacklist would be incredibly useful, it could really cut down on the number of retag requests.

Comment: Feature request is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list

Answer (score 7):

Went through and took care of these.

Comment: Damn. No wonder I could find them.

Comment: @Diago and @TheTXI Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is what happens when I can't sleep on a week night.

Comment: It's bright and early in the morning for me :)

Comment: @Alex - Same here. @TheTXI - I got to bed around 3:00am this morning and was up at 6:30am. Sleeping is becoming a bit of problem for me lately.